# why getStaticProps not not working in page

Tags: next.js, getstaticprops

why getStaticProps function not working. even inside a valid page.

this is folder structure with target file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkVg7.png)

The console inside getStaticProps() does not print anything & the console inside Home() prints "undefined".

Comment: `getStaticProps` only works with `pages` router, it does not work with `app` router. Make sure you are reading the correct version of docs, in your case you need `app` docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticProps()` is not works with `app` directory. In app directory every every thing will be server-side rendering.